# USB differential signal from single pin?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, differential

I'd like to make a device similar to the "Digispark", but what really bugs me about those (and most, if not all, V-USB designs, at least all I could find online), is the "waste" of a GPIO pin which is just the negative of another pin for the differential pair. so I wondered if there's an easy (and cheap+small, so low chip count) way to do the differential pair to single ended full duplex conversion?

methods I know of:

- using an opamp to convert differential pair to single ended
- using a NOT gate to convert single ended to differential pair

the problem is I obviously couldn't just put those two in parallel, or I'd produce a feedback loop.

Is this even possible without having a dedicated IC that understands USB or another "wasted" pin to indicate the direction? the circuit would have to distinguish between a driven output and a high-impedance input pin in real time essentially, and I have no idea if or how that could be achieved.

Comment: USB is not true differential. There are states that require both D+ and D- to be low.

Comment: What are you going to use the extra pin for? If it is a microcontroller with a built-in USB peripheral and a diff pair of signals, you won't be able to use it for anything else.

Comment: @EugeneSh. V-USB is a "virtual USB" implementation - allows AVRs with no USB peripheral to emulate USB.

Comment: @EugeneSh. as hinted by my mention of V-USB and "cheap", it's not a USB peripheral (because those usually cost more), but essentially low-speed USB1.1 bit banging. the Digisparks for example run on an ATtiny85

Comment: @TomCarpenter I just learned that after posting my question. kinda ugly if you ask me but I guess that means I really just can't do it?

Comment: @nonchip I suppose it's a little ugly, but it's also quite clever in that it allows additional sideband control wires to be embedded within the two data lines.

Comment: You could look at the ATtiny861 which has more pins and is still inexpensive.  Unclear if it's an official V-USB target but there are indications people have gotten it to work.  But realistically, consider something cheap with a true USB device engine.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah if i needed anything fast i'd definitely go for true USB, but i just want to make a cheap, prototype-y (i have a bunch of attiny13 and -85s and atmega8s lying around) thing to essentially convert USB CDC to 1-64KB/s SPI mode 3 with 2 additional commands parsed by the uC.

Comment: @nonchip are you brave enough to blow the reset fuse?  That would yield another I/O (I believe you can get it back with a high voltage programmer)

Comment: @ChrisStratton on a 12cents attiny? yeah i think just flashing one PER code change would be even cheaper than building (nobody can afford to buy) an HV programmer ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

USB is not always differential. There are signalling states that require both D+ and D- to be low.

Additionally D+/D- are used for other purposes, such as performing reset and speed detection which require sense resistor configurations to be changed.

The pin isn't "wasted", it's "required". I suppose you should think of it less like a differential pair, and more like a clever two-wire communication protocol that is sometimes used differential to improve speed and immunity, and sometimes single ended to do control stuff.

Comment: i wasn't aware of that before (D+/- are usually just described as a differential pair, and the names also really hint towards that), but yeah ok, obviously i can't do it then (except by adding a dedicated "usb to 1 wire" ic or something like that, which... no. :P)